# asp.NET resources inside an attribute of a control

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following works when I use control properties:
`<asp:Button Text="<%$Resources:MyResource, SomeText %>" runat="server"/>`

I need a solution to implement this:

1. `<asp:Button Text="pre <%$Resources:MyResource, SomeText %> post" runat="server"/>`
2. `<asp:TextBox placeholder="<%$Resources:MyResource, SomeText %>" runat="server"/>`

Is there any workaround to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is, you can not use `<% .. %>` inside asp.net server controls ( that has `runat=server` ).

Solution is to do this in server-side code , say in page_load add following code .

`txt.Attributes.Add("placeholder", Properties.Resources.MyResource);` -- this for #2 part of your question.

Or use javascript to save that value using `<% .. %>` and in javascript(that will be loaded in body load, or dom ready) set required properties.